# Tables seem to be overwritten

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I am trying to use VBA to open a Word document from within Excel, and insert some tables into the document. The tables are populated with information from Excel.

Each table seems to overwrite the previous one.

Here is an update, I need to make sure a table doesn't form inside a table.[THis is an example of what Is going on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHQzK.png)

How can I avoid this?

```
    Dim intNoOfRows
    Dim intNoOfColumns
    Dim objWord
    Dim objDoc
    Dim objRange
    Dim objTable

    intNoOfRows = 5
    intNoOfColumns = 3

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = True    

    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add    

    Set objRange = objDoc.Range

    objDoc.Tables.Add objRange, intNoOfRows, intNoOfColumns    

    Set objTable = objDoc.Tables(1)

    objTable.Borders.Enable = True   

    For i = 1 To intNoOfRows
        For j = 1 To intNoOfColumns

        Next
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to collapse the range you are using to insert? But it's impossible to know without some code.

Comment: shoot, that didnt paste like I thought, one moment

Comment: http://excel-macro.tutorialhorizon.com/vba-excel-add-table-and-fill-data-to-the-word-document/

Comment: this is the link for the code I am trying to work with

Comment: You can edit your question by clicking on `Edit` below it (or by clicking [**this link**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45537647/edit) directly). Then you can paste your code in there, using `CTRL+ K` to format it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The Word object model has the concept of a Range; you can think of it as the current block of text that you want to work with in the program.

This line:

```
objDoc.Tables.Add objRange, intNoOfRows, intNoOfColumns
```

adds a new table to the given range (`objRange`).

Looking at the parameter list in the [documentation for the `Add` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/tables-add-method-word), we see the following (emphasis added):

> **Name**: Range
>
> **Description**: The range where you want the table to appear. *The table replaces the range, if the range isn't collapsed.*

Looking at the previous line of your code:

```
Set objRange = objDoc.Range
```

the range extends over the entire document. This is probably not what you want, as it will replace not only any other tables, but also any other text in the document.

In order to collapse the range, call the [`Collapse` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/range-collapse-method-word). Ranges can be collapsed in two ways: either the end of the range should move to the start of the range, or the range start should move to the end of the range. This behavior is controlled by passing in `wdCollapseStart` or `wdCollapseEnd` to the `Collapse` method, or their equivalent values:

```
'objRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
objRange.Collapse 1
```

Once you've collapsed the range, then you can add the new table.

```
objDoc.Tables.Add objRange, intNoOfRows, intNoOfColumns
```

---

N.B. Your code is using late binding, which means (among other things) that the editor isn't aware of the shapes of the various objects you are using.

To provide the editor with this information, add a reference (**Tools** -> **References...**) to the **Microsoft Word Object Model** (or something similar).

Then, when you declare your variables, you can specify their type:

```
Dim objDoc As Word.Document
```

Now, when you write `oDoc.`, the editor can tell you which methods and properties are available for a Word document.

---

There's another issue with this code. Once the table is inserted, there are a few lines of processing done on the table. But the processing is never done on the most recently added table in the document, but rather always on the first table in the document:

```
objDoc.Tables.Add objRange, intNoOfRows, intNoOfColumns
Set objTable = objDoc.Tables(1) 'reference to the first table in the document
```

The simplest way to fix this, would be to use the reference returned from adding the table:

```
'we need the parentheses now because we're using the returned value
Set objTable = objDoc.Tables.Add(objRange, intNoOfRows, intNoOfColumns)
```

---

The final code could look something like this:

```
Dim objWord As New Word.Application

'in production, keeping the application invisible is often more performant
'but while debugging, it's useful to see what's going on in the application
objWord.Visible = True

Dim objDoc As Word.Document
Set objDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add

Dim objRange As Word.Range
Set objRange = objDoc.Range
objRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

Dim intNoOfRows As Integer
intNoOfRows = 5
Dim intNoOfColumns As Integer
intNoOfColumns = 3
Dim objTable As Word.Table
Set objTable = objDoc.Tables.Add(objRange, intNoOfRows, intNoOfColumns)

'Fill the table here

'Collapse the range again (not sure this is needed)
objRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
'Now you can add a new table:
Set objTable = objDoc.Tables.Add(objRange, intNoOfRows, intNoOfColumns)
```

Comment: Thanks for this! A couple of questions... do I use the collapse method in transition to make my other tables and use the same lines of code I posted afterwords?

Comment: once i collapse, i still am unsure how to place the table right under the previous table I made.

Comment: @user8426180 RE _other lines of code_: Yes. Once you've inserted the new table into the document, you don't need the range anymore, because you have a reference to the table itself. The only reason why you need the range is in order to tell Word where in the document you want to insert the table.

Comment: @user8426180 RE your other comment, I've updated my answer with what I think is the solution. But what problem are you having when you try to place one table after the other?

Comment: please add how in the code I have you would modify how I set the range and add tables, and also show the transition to creating a second table. For example, where I would collapse the range and how I would refer to the second table. I am running into errors like, "can't delete the range" or "no object". Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user8426180 Updated. You should probably provide more details as to where you are getting these errors.

Comment: Thanks again! This worked to add another table. However, the table is in the first box of my original graph. I tried moving the cursor down and starting the range after the first table, but was unable to successfully do so. Do you have any idea what is going on here?Thanks so much

Comment: @user8426180 _original graph_?? Not sure what you mean. Also, keep in mind that the selection and the range are two different things -- the current position of the cursor or the selection is also something the user sees and can interact with; the range doesn't exist outside of the program being written.

Comment: I have attached a link in the original post to show what I mean. In terms of using the cursor to start a range, that sounds like a bad idea now that I am more clear. I would like to start the new range after the first table and so on. how does that work